# UIViewController receives notification and push segues on button press, but need to prevent multiple button presses and segues

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, nsnotificationcenter

I have a `UINavigationController` with a root view controller. My `UINavigationController` is also set as my app's `Initial View Controller`.

Throughout my entire app, whenever I want to segue, I use the following code:

```
MyViewController *myVC = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myVC animated:YES];
```

This works perfectly.

I just setup a new universal button for my app that is shown on every single screen of my app. If the user presses this button, then 3 more buttons appear, and if they tap one of those 3 buttons, then a segue needs to happen.

When one of the 3 buttons is pressed I post a notification via `NSNotificationCenter`. All of my UIViewControllers register as observers for this notification, and when they receive it they are told to push a view controller using the same code I posted above.

This works perfectly. The user is pushed to the new `UIViewController`.

However, if the user presses my universal button again, and then taps the same button, it just pushes the same `UIViewController` again even though they are already on that one.

I have never really had things setup this way so I'm unsure what to do at this point. If they have already been pushed to that view controller, then I need to prevent them from being pushed there again.

Comment: Shouldn't you disable the button that takes them to that view controller if they are already on it?

Comment: @MikeTaverne Yes, this is definitely another possibility.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up adding string identifiers to each button. When a button is pressed, the string identifier is passed. Based on the string identifier, I store the selected `UIViewController` class in a property.

If the selected `UIViewController` class matches the `UINavigationController's` `visibleViewController` property, then I don't post the segue notification.